# click on link and scroll to particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, slide

I am developing a page with horizontal scrolling in which if I click on a link, the html view will scroll to specified `div` to the left but the issue is when I click on a link which is Home, About us or product, `div` is scrolled but parts of the `div` comes with second `div` like "about Us" comes in "product" `div`

**[Demo](http://darf.t15.org/#home)**

and code is

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Dynakode- GPS vehicle tracking System India, GPS Trackers, Fleet Management solutions</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Dynakode provide GPS based Vehicle Tracking System and provides accurate location of your Vehicle." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="gps, vehicle tracking, fleet management, tracking unit, theft protection, vehicle tracking, mobile tracking, vehicle theft, track india, track car, gps auto faremeter, gps software, dimts delhi, dynakode, geofencing,gps dimts, g-71 dimts, gps dealers, gps vehicle tracking, fleet management" />
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Dynakode" />
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Complete GPS/GPRS vehicle tracking solution in NCR India. Visit us at http://track.dynakode.com for more." />
    <meta itemprop="image" content="http://track.dynakode.com/static/images/logo.png" />
    <meta name="robots" content="INDEX/FOLLOW">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href="css/jInvertScroll.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class="inner">

    <!--[Headeer]-->
    <header>
        <div class="content">
            <?php
            include './template/header.php';
            ?>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="slideshow" style="margin-top:100px;">
        <?php
        include './template/slide.php';
        ?>
    </section>
    <!--[/Slideshow]--> 
    <!--[Container]-->
    <div class="container">
        <!--[/Headeer]--> 
        <!--[Slideshow]-->
        <?php include './template/slide_login.php'; ?>
        <div class="front scroll">
            <div id="home" class="test">

            </div>
            <div id="aboutus" class="test">

            </div>
            <div id="products" class="test">

            </div>
            <div id="soluation" class="test">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <?php
        include './template/footer.php';
        ?>
    </footer>  
    <!--[/Footer]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <?php
    include './template/analyticstracking.php';
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jInvertScroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $.jInvertScroll(['.scroll']);
        }(jQuery));

    </script>
    <script  type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var target = this.hash,
                        $target = $(target);

                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.position().left
                }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
                    window.location.hash = target;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

scrolling Script is

```
  <script  type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var target = this.hash,
                            $target = $(target);

                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        'scrollTop': $target.position().left
                    }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
                        window.location.hash = target;
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: You could just check the value of the `top` attribute of all divs on load in pixels, and then assign that value to the scrolling code.

Comment: what I meant was, use `offsetTop` to get the coordinate of all divs and store their values in seperate variables, and then in your scrolling part of the code just use the values of those variables to scroll to that particular coordinate/pixel.